# How do you get a specific select option value in PHP for other field

Tags: php

I've got this line of code which allows the user to input a state;

```
<input id="location-state" type="text" maxlength="2" name="location_state" value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

but, I want to change that into a selection from a drop down. Now one way I thought of doing it was to use php and grab the selection option value and add that to the above input, then hide the input from user ever seeing it.

Not sure where to start, I've tried doing the following as a test but didn't work;

```
<select>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'AL'); ?>">Alabama</option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'AK'); ?>">Alaska</option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'AZ'); ?>AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'AR'); ?>AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'CA'); ?>CA">California</option>
</select>
```

It does sort of work, but only for Alabama...

Comment: if `$EM_Location->location_state == AZ` you want Arizona to be selected ?

Comment: For AZ, AR, and CA you're doing both `echo esc_attr(...)` and also printing the hard-coded abbreviation right after it, so you get `value="AZAZ"`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: yes, so rather then typing a state... I want people to select it.. and it looks like `$EM_Location->location_state` sets the value in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values = array(
    'AL' => 'Alabama',
    'AK' => 'Alaska',
    'AZ' => 'Arizona'
    ...
);


echo '<select id="location-state" name="location_state">';

foreach( $values as $key => $value )
{
    $selected = $key == $EM_Location->location_state ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'" '.$selected.'>'.$value.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: this works, looks like it does, but the first one `'AL' => 'Alabama'` doesn't show up...

Comment: Are you sure is was set in `$values` ?

Comment: yes, ... looks like I have to set the first one empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your input tag and give the select tag an attribute name with the same value as it was input's.
Remove this:

```
<input id="location-state" type="text" maxlength="2" name="location_state" value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

And add this:

```
<select name="location_state">
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'AL'); ?>">Alabama</option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'AK'); ?>">Alaska</option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'AZ'); ?>AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'AR'); ?>AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr($EM_Location->location_state, 'CA'); ?>CA">California</option>
</select>
```

And you have no need to change your php code.

Comment: Nope, the above doesn't work tried it already. Sorry and thank you